# Set TextMate 2 as default editor

Tags: macos, file-association, textmate-2

How do I set TextMate 2 as default editor for text files in Mac OSX Sierra?

According to the 2nd answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370584/mac-os-x-set-textmate-as-default-text-editor I tried:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.macromates.textmate;}'
```

But it doesn't seem to work - when I open a file with a `.txt` extension it opens in TextEdit.

Note that I'm *not* looking for a manual solution like the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370584/mac-os-x-set-textmate-as-default-text-editor

Answer (score 2):

You need to write to `com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure`:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure \
    LSHandlers -array-add \
    '{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.macromates.textmate;}'
```

Then log out for the change to take effect.

Comment: Doesn't work :(